# each child in a list should have unique 'key' prop

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I keep getting this warning "each child in a list should have unique 'key' prop" even though I have unique items with different keys.

Whenever I create a new 'plant' object I give it a new uuid

```
    setPlants(prevItems => {
      return [
        {name: newPlantName, key: uuid.v4(), timeInterval: null},
        ...prevItems,
      ];
```

And my listItem component is set up with a key

```
<ListItem
        key={plant.key}
```

Whenever I print my list all the 'keys' have a different uuid. The warning occurs every time I refresh the app so it might be somehow because i'm using a database to access the data? I'm not really sure but I am using mmkv to store the data from my state and then I show that data when the app first opens.

This is the full mapping:

```
  {plants &&
    plants.map(plant =>
      plant ? (
        <PlantItem
          plant={plant}
          deletion={openDeleteOrCancel}
          setPlants={setPlants}
        />
      ) : null,
    )}
```

PlantItem component:

```
  return (
    <>
      <ActionSheet
        visible={actionSheetVisible}
        closeOverlay={() => {
          setActionSheetVisible(false);
        }}
        actions={actions}
      />

      <ListItem
        key={plant.key}
        onPress={() => {
          setActionSheetVisible(true);
        }}
        bottomDivider>
        <ListItem.Content key={plant.key} style={styles.listItemContainer}>
          <ListItem.Title>{plant.name}</ListItem.Title>
          {/* <Icon name="check" size={20} /> */}
        </ListItem.Content>
      </ListItem>
      {showAddTimeInterval && (
        <AddTimeInterval
          createTimeInterval={createTimeInterval}
          closeModal={toggleShowAddTimeInterval}
          plantName={plant.name}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
```

This is how my states are initiated

```
  const [plantsStorage, setPlantsStorage] = useStorage('plantss');

  const [plants, setPlants] = useState(plantsStorage ? plantsStorage : []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPlantsStorage(plants);
  });
```

The warning is just really annoying, if there is no way to change my code to fix it is there a way to mute it somehow? just for this specific warning not all warnings.

Comment: How are you mapping the children? Please update question to include a complete and comprehensive code example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The React key should be used on the ***outermost*** mapped element.

React [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

```
{plants.map(plant =>
  plant ? (
    <PlantItem
      key={plant.key} // <-- use key here!
      plant={plant}
      deletion={openDeleteOrCancel}
      setPlants={setPlants}
    />
  ) : null,
)}
```

Suggestion, filter the `plants` array to remove the null "holes".

```
{plants
  .filter(Boolean) // include only truthy plant objects
  .map(plant => (
    <PlantItem
      key={plant.key} // <-- use key here!
      plant={plant}
      deletion={openDeleteOrCancel}
      setPlants={setPlants}
    />)
)}
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much been stuck on it for ages, did not realise it was this simple haha. I thought you cannot put a key when passing in props, I thought you would only put it for the component that is actually listing the items but I guess I was wrong. Either way thank you so much for your help and your time!